# Is there a way to validate Heapbox elements using jQuery Validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, heapbox

I'm building a form that uses a heapBox (https://github.com/FilipBartos/heapbox) replacement for the `<select>` elements, and also uses jQuery Validate for form validation.

jQuery Validate only works on form elements with a name attribute, so because heapbox replaces the `<select>` elements with divs, its not recognised in the validation process.

I have error messages that are appended to each input, and then also an overall summary of the errors which appears on an invalid form submission. Would it be possible to write something in javascript that doesn't use the plugin, just for the heapbox elements? I'm not sure I'd know where to start.

I know that I could go back to using the default `<select>` elements and have limited control over the styles, but I really wanted to see if there is a way around this.

Here's my code:

```html
<form class="form" id="register-form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-fields">
        <label>Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" required/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-fields">
        <label>Lastname</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" required/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-fields">
        <label>Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" required/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-fields">
        <label>Confirm email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email_again" required/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-fields">
        <label>Telephone</label>
        <input type="tel" name="telephone" required/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-fields">
        <label>Mobile number</label>
        <input type="tel" name="mobile" required/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-fields">
        <label>How did you hear about us?</label>
        <select class="custom-select" name="findUs" required>
          <option value="default">Please select from the following...</option>
          <option value="Option 1">option 1</option>
          <option value="Option 2">option 2</option>
          <option value="Option 3">option 3</option>
          <option value="Option 4">option 4</option>
          <option value="Option 5"> option 5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
$(".custom-select").heapbox();  

var submitted = false;
    var validator = jQuery("#register-form").validate({ 
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        var summary = "";
        if (submitted) {
            var summary = "";
            jQuery.each(errorList, function() {
            summary += "<li><label for='"+ this.element.name;
            summary += "' class='formError'>" + this.message + "</label></li>"; });
            jQuery("#error-messages").show();
            jQuery("#error-messages").find('.error-list ul').html(summary);
            submitted = false;
        }
        this.defaultShowErrors();
  },          
  invalidHandler: function(form, validator) { submitted = true; },
  onfocusout: function(element) { this.element(element); },
  errorClass: "error",
  rules: {

    },
    messages: {

    }          
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that HeapBox behaves similarly to Chosen.  It hides the original `select` and replaces it.

You'll need to do a few things, the first item at the very least...

1. Activate validation on hidden elements so that the original `select` elements are validated.

   ```
   jQuery("#register-form").validate({
       ignore: [],  // ignore nothing, validate everything
       // remaining options...
   ```

   You can set `ignore` to `[]`, which means "ignore nothing", or you can set it to some other selector if there are other hidden form elements you need ignored.
2. Since the error messages are going to be appended immediately *after* the hidden `select` element, you'd have to conditionally use `errorPlacement` to fix this.  However, since you're using the `showErrors` function to construct your messages elsewhere, this is a moot point.
3. Since validation is triggered when the user interacts with the `select` element, interacting with the HeapBox `div` *may* not trigger validation on this element.  If that's the case, create a custom handler to fix it.  Since the HeapBox developer's demo page is dead, for my example I will assume the HeapBox `div` has a class of `.heapbox`...

   ```
   $('div.heapbox').on('mouseleave blur', function() {
       $('select[name="findUs"]').valid(); // trigger validation on select
   });
   ```

   So when the `mouseleave` or `blur` events fire on the HeapBox `div`, the `.valid()` method attached to your hidden `select` element is forced to validate it.

**NOTES**:  *HeapBox has [not been touched since Feb 2014](https://github.com/FilipBartos/heapbox/tree/master/src), there are several [open GitHub issues stretching back to 2013](https://github.com/FilipBartos/heapbox/issues), and [the developer's official demo page is giving a 404](http://www.bartos.me/heapbox).  You may want to use a more up-to-date and better maintained plugin for your project.*